# Modify days counter on datetime [Python]

Tags: python, date, datetime

I have this code and I want to count the days between 2 dates.

```
from datetime import date, datetime

checkin= datetime(2022, 1, 30, 1, 15, 00)
checkout= datetime(2022, 1, 31, 0, 0, 00)
count_days= (checkout - checkin).days
```

In this case, the result of count_days result is 0, because in an operation with 2 datetimes, it takes into account hours, minutes and seconds.

I want the result to be 1 because is +1 day of difference. Type of variables **must** be datetimes. Thanks!

Comment: This code prints 0 because there is not a full day of difference between the two times; there is only 22 hours and 45 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert them to dates first, with the `date` method.

```py
from datetime import date, datetime

checkin = datetime(2022, 1, 30, 1, 15, 00)
checkout = datetime(2022, 1, 31, 0, 0, 00)
count_days = (checkout.date() - checkin.date()).days
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like this?

(assuming you want a minimum since the solution you have is similar)

```py
from datetime import date, datetime

check_in= datetime(2022, 1, 30, 1, 15, 00)
check_out= datetime(2022, 1, 31, 0, 0, 00)

# Number of days between two dates (min 1 day)
days = (check_out - check_in).days + 1

print(days)
```

Comment: How is this any different from the code already in the question?

Comment: Great question, it was updated

Comment: You can't just arbitrarily add one.  If those two datetimes are on the same day, the difference should be zero, but your code would print one.